# How do i get an interval of date in xquery 1.0

Tags: date, xquery

with a start date and an end date, i want a list of the dates between the 2. 
I tried this  :

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $startdate:= xs:string(current-date())
let $enddate:= xs:string(current-date()+ xs:yearMonthDuration("P2Y6M"))
let $datelist := for $x in ($startdate to $enddate) return $x
```

But i get the error that the for is only for int.
Moreover, at the end I want my datelist to be :

```
1901
1902
1903
1904
...
```

Where '19' is the last two number of the year and '01' '02' the number of the month.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can generate the sequence of `xs:date` values as follows:

```
let $startdate:= current-date()
let $duration := xs:yearMonthDuration("P2Y6M")
let $months := years-from-duration($duration) * 12 + months-from-duration($duration)
for $month in 0 to $months
return $startdate + xs:yearMonthDuration(concat("P", $month, "M"))
```

If in the end you don't want `xs:date`s but rather the string format you have shown then use `format-date` as needed.

Comment: I would do `let $oneMonth := $xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M'), $months := $duration div $oneMonth` and `return $oneMonth * $month`, but it's a minor detail.

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, `$months := $duration div $oneMonth` is more in line with the arithmetic features the duration and date data types in XQuery and XSLT and XPath 2 and later give us. Although it seems it returns an `xs:decimal` so the `0 to $months` then needs to be `0 to xs:integer($months)`.